# PHP Comprehensive Object Difference Function

Tags: php, object, recursion, comparison

Does anyone know of a php function that will take in two objects and return a complete set of differences back as an object?

I'll use json encoded data as an example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

Object A:

```
{
    "Name":"Original",
    "Id": 5,
    "Data":{
        "Value1": 1,
        "Value2": [
            5, 7, 8, 10
        ],
        "Value3": {
            "Exists": true
        }
    }
}
```

Object B:

```
{
    "Name":"ThisNameChanged",
    "Id": 5,
    "Data":{
        "Value1": 7,
        "Value2": [
            5, 8, 9
        ],
        "Value3": {
            "Exists": true
        }
    }
}
```

Would return:

```
{
    "Name":"ThisNameChanged",
    "Data":{
        "Value2": {
            "1": 8,
            "2": 9
        }
    }
}
```

If no such function exists (which I guess is likely), how might I write a function to do this? Would anyone be able to provide an example, or the function?

Comment: By "comprehensive" do you also mean object types? So, if two objects have the exact same values but are of two different types, should they be considered as different? What about objects that inherit from the same base class? Should they be considered as the same? What about inaccessible members? Should they be ignored? This could be solved rather easily using recursion, but you have to be very specific by what you mean by "difference".

Comment: In this case, it would not care what the type of an object is, or if it extends any objects. Inaccessible members should be ignored as well, it should only compare publicly visible parameters of an object. Recursion was indeed what I had in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Kim Alexander, I was able to write a code that accomplished what I was looking to do.

```
function objDiff($obj1, $obj2, $diff = null) {
    if (is_null($diff))
        $diff = new stdClass;

    $obj1Arr = (array)$obj1;
    $obj2Arr = (array)$obj2;

    foreach($obj1Arr as $key => $val) {
        if (isset($obj2Arr[$key]))
        {
            if ($obj2Arr[$key] != $val)
            {
                if (is_object($obj2Arr[$key]) && is_object($val))
                    $diff->$key = objDiff($val, $obj2Arr[$key]);
                else
                    $diff->$key = $obj2Arr[$key];
            }
        }
    }
    return $diff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is some simple example of function you ask for,

but it is not perfect, just food for thought for you:

```
function objDiff ($obj1, $obj2) {
        $diff=array();
    $obj1Arr = (array)$obj1;
    $obj2Arr = (array)$obj2;

    foreach ($obj1Arr as $key=>$val) {

        if (!(isset($obj2Arr[$key]) && $obj2Arr[$key]===$val  )) {
            if (gettype($val)=='object') {

                if (isset($obj2Arr[$key])) {
                    if (gettype($obj2Arr[$key])=='object') {
                        $subDiff = objDiff($val,$obj2Arr[$key]);
                        $diff[$key]=$subDiff;
                    } else {
                        $diff[$key]=array($val,$obj2Arr[$key]);
                    }
                } else {
                    $diff[$key]=array($val,$obj2Arr[$key]);
                }
            } else {
                $diff[$key]=array($val,(isset($obj2Arr[$key]))?$obj2Arr[$key]:null);
            }
        }
    }
    return $diff;
}
```

with this data:

```
$obj1 = new stdClass();
    $obj1->test1 = 1;
    $obj1->test2 = 2;
       $subObj = new stdClass();
    $subObj->test1 = 1;
    $subObj->test2 = 2;
    $obj1->test3 = $subObj;
        $obj2 = new stdClass();
    $obj2->test1 = 3;
    $obj2->test2 = 4;
    $subObj = new stdClass();
    $subObj->test1 = 3;
    $subObj->test2 = 2;
    $obj2->test3 = $subObj;

 print_r(objDiff($obj1,$obj2) );
```

it returns:

```
Array
(
    [test1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 3
        )

    [test2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 4
        )

    [test3] => Array
        (
            [test1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 3
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks, this isn't quite what I needed, but I was able to build upon what you gave me here to get what I needed.